# Kotlin Debug mode , variables always shows collecting data

Tags: android, kotlin, adb

Android Studio ,In Debug mode , variables always shows collecting data for kotline classes . Interesting is java classes, activities it works fine. Any idea about this issue.

**studio version : 3.1.3
kotlin_version = '1.1.51'**

Tried **android.enableD8=true** solution. still bug is exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible of some IDEA cache issue. 1) Close project IDEA, open in Explorer, and delete folders `./idea` and `./gradle`. Then open IDEA and **Import new Project**.

Comment: problem solved, it works  fine in latest kotlin versions